# EditText On update/onChange value Add listener

Tags: java, android

I have 2 EditText in my activity,lets say `editText1` ,`editText2` and A Double Variable `d=200`

I want when user change/insert value for `editText1` ,`editText2` value will update in real Time as `editText1*d`

Also when user change/insert value for editText2 ,editText1 will be update in real time as `editText2*d`

I tried to use `addTextChangedListener->onTextChanged`but it works fine for one Edit text,when I set this function for both editText then application crash 
because its creating an infinite loop,how can I solve this problem?

update :bellow is my code

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                            Editable a = et1.getText();
                            Double aa = Double.parseDouble(a.toString())*100;
                            String aaa = aa.toString();

                            et2.setText(aaa);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        }
                    });

                    et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                            Editable b=et2.getText();
                            Double bb=Double.parseDouble(b.toString());
                            String bbb=bb.toString();
                            et1.setText(bbb);


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: it normal it will create a infinite loop since when you edit value in ed1 , ed2 is editing and when you edit vale in ed2 , ed1 is editing and vis versa ....please add you code

Comment: Yes I understand problem .what is proper method to do this?I added my codes

Comment: You can add a boolean to monitor if you should use `setText()` for the other editText or not.

Answer (score 1):

EditText et1, et2;

```
TextWatcher watcher1 = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Editable a = et1.getText();
        Double aa = Double.parseDouble(a.toString())*100;
        String aaa = aa.toString();
        et2.removeTextChangedListener(watcher2);
        et2.setText(aaa);
        et2.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

TextWatcher watcher2 = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Editable b=et2.getText();
        Double bb=Double.parseDouble(b.toString());
        String bbb=bb.toString();
        et1.removeTextChangedListener(watcher1);
        et1.setText(bbb);
        et1.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

```java
et1.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);
et2.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
```

Comment: Editable a = et1.getText();
        Double aa = Double.parseDouble(a.toString())*100;
        String aaa = aa.toString();
        et2.removeTextChangedListener(watcher2);//(watcher2 is not accessible)
        et2.setText(aaa);
        et2.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);//(watcher2 is not accessible)

Comment: watcher1 and watcher2 are member variables in Activity or fragment. not local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a TextWatcher, It works pretty much like how it sounds. When the user changes (adds/removes text from) what is existing in the `EditText`, it will "Activate" this class. To test it out, you can use logs or set a breakpoint at any one of these statements.

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         //Your action here
          edit = fromEditText.getText().toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
}
```

and in `onCreate`, add this to connect your `EditText` to the `TextWatcher`

```
fromEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MainActivity.MyTextWatcher(fromEditText));
```

You can add a bunch of `EditText`'s to a single `TextWatcher`. All you need to do is rinse and repeat. Just change the name of the respective `EditText` and add it to the `TextWatcher`. Be aware, that if you have some `EditText` change the text of another `EditText`, it can result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Not clear in this concept,I am beginner.I have created a new class ,implement Textwatcher and added methods,then dont understand what to do

Comment: If you copied everything , you can run the code. If you want to copy from one edit text to another call the edit text and set the text with the results from the earlier edit text. If you just want to run a code everytime the user changes the text , you could also put it in the text watcher

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to create `textwatcher` separately then in your `TextWatcher_EdOne`

```
 TextWatcher  TextWatcher_EdOne   = new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    //disable editext2 textwatcher 
                    et2.removeTextChangedListener(TextWatcher_EdTwo);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                       ///do your stuff


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                     // enable textwatcher on et2 again                                
                     et2.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher_EdTwo);

                    }
                }
```

and will do it for the other textWatcher , this way you will avoid infinite loop

Comment: Something like this , you will have control to start watching your edittext when you have to and not all the time

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2sk79CQs here I added coments for error,can you take a look plz?

Comment: You have to create a final and global variable textwatcher outside on create

Comment: Got it and working but input text Direction is Right to left insted of left to right.How can I solve it?

Comment: I mean bug is want to type 125 but its typing 521

Comment: I really don't know that is happening but there is nothing wrong with the text watcher , please check the input in your edittexts

Comment: when not using removeTextWatcher and addTextwatcher then no problem in input,

Comment: Could you try with addtextchangedllistener(null) instead of remove